# Recycler views inside nested scroll views causing lag when filtering with search bar

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I'm working on this view with a header at the top and a search bar beneath it, followed by a nested scroll view which contains a linear layout that further consists of 2 recycler views. The layout xml file can be found below.

The problem I'm facing is that when I filter the items in the recycler views through search bar, there is a noticeable lag at rendering filtered results. I have pinpointed the problem to the nested scroll view because when I get rid of this (only having 2 recycler views), the problem of lagging goes away completely. However, of course, with the nested scroll view gone, I can no longer scroll 2 recycler views at the same time.

Right now, I have 2 adapters for each recycler view, and each adapter implements the Filterable interface which handles the filtering logic. Further more, I have a view model class and a fragment class.

If this problem cannot be solved easily, then I think the last resort would be to get rid of the nested scroll view and have only one recycler view that contains both lists, and reduce the number of adapters to one. This would make the logic really complicated so I hope there is another way of workaround.

Please let me know what you guys think. Any input is appreciated.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/invite_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/component_bars_navigation_nav_sub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/XXXL"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        layout="@layout/layout_component_bars_row_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/add_friend_header" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/invite_list_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search_bar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/invite_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/XXXXL"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/label_1"
                layout="@layout/layout_component_bars_row_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/S"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:itemCount="3"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-50dp"
                tools:listitem="@layout/components_1_item"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/label_2"
                layout="@layout/layout_component_bars_row_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/S"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:itemCount="2"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-50dp"
                tools:listitem="@layout/components_2_item"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why not have just 1 recyclerview with multiple view types? that way you wouldn't need the nestedscrollview either

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution that solves this problem. Instead of doing multiple recycler views, I combined them into one with multiple view types.

In case people are still confused, the following links may help because they helped me :)

[Android RecyclerView with multiple view type (multiple view holder)](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b)

[Working with RecyclerView and multiple view types](https://medium.com/@paulnunezm/working-with-recyclerview-and-multiple-view-types-bb1e7dfc6993)